# find repeating unknown value from different keys of subarrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an Array like this. this is a connection log of some devices to Internet.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[src_ip] => x
[src_port] => 48755
[dst_ip] => y
[dst_port] => 443
[device_id] => 22040

)

[1] => Array
(
[src_ip] => x
[src_port] => 48754
[dst_ip] => y
[dst_port] => 443
[device_id] => 22040
)

[2] => Array
(
[src_ip] => z
[src_port] => 443
[dst_ip] => x
[dst_port] => 54267
[device_id] => 22040

)... more than 1000 row!)
```

source IP: [src_ip] and destination IP: [dst_ip] based on Sending or Receiving connection states change their position.
we don't know current network state (sending/receiving)
also we don't know current IP of device.
IP of device is fixed but sometimes it placed on [src_ip] sometimes in [dst_ip]

but we can see repeating and continuous occurrence of an IP in either in [src_ip] or [dst_ip]  of all subarrays (rows) which show us the IP of communicating device.
how can find IP of device in this array using PHP? ( most repeating IP in first 100 row  for example)

we can not use IP Address range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = [
    [ 'src_ip' => '5B---45A', 'src_port' => 48755, 'dst_ip' => '0A---223', 'dst_port' => 443, 'device_id' => 22040 ],
    [ 'src_ip' => '5B---45A', 'src_port' => 48754, 'dst_ip' => '0A---223', 'dst_port' => 443, 'device_id' => 22040 ],
    [ 'src_ip' => '11---D2B', 'src_port' => 443, 'dst_ip' => '5B---45A', 'dst_port' => 54267, 'device_id' => 22040 ],
    [ 'src_ip' => '11---D2B', 'src_port' => 443, 'dst_ip' => '5B---45A', 'dst_port' => 54267, 'device_id' => 22039 ],
    [ 'src_ip' => '11---D2B', 'src_port' => 443, 'dst_ip' => '0A---223', 'dst_port' => 54267, 'device_id' => 22040 ]
];
```

If *device_id* is irrelevant:

```
$section = array_slice($data, 0, 99);
$result = array_count_values([ ...array_column($section, 'src_ip'), ...array_column($section, 'dst_ip') ]);
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
     [5B---45A] => 4
     [11---D2B] => 3
     [0A---223] => 3
)
```

If *device_id* matters, first filter for it:

```
$section = array_slice(array_filter ($data, fn($item) => $item['device_id'] === 22040), 0, 99);
$result = array_count_values([ ...array_column($section, 'src_ip'), ...array_column($section, 'dst_ip') ]);
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
     [5B---45A] => 3
     [11---D2B] => 2
     [0A---223] => 3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract values using `array_column`, then you count the values using `array_count_values` and last, you use `max` for the most used IPs.

An example:

```php
<?php

$src = array_column($connections, 'src_ip');
$dst = array_column($connections, 'dst_ip');

$count = array_count_values(array_merge($src, $dst));
$max = array_keys($count, max($count));

print_r($count);
print_r($max);
```